# VB.NET Progress Bar issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file-io, progress-bar, sleep

I want another form to open with a progress bar when a button is clicked. So far the execution freezes for a couple of seconds and then the progress bar form opens up with the progress bar full, and then closes. I want the main form to pause execution so that the file isn't written until the progress bar has finished doing it's thing. Here's my code:

> Main class:

```
Private Sub btnWriteFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWriteFile.Click
    If hasUserEnteredFileName() = True Then 'don't worry about this
        If reversedString IsNot Nothing Then 'or this
            FileWriting.Show() 'the progress bar class
            Dim sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\" & fileName.Text & ".txt")
            sw.Write(reversedString)
            sw.Flush()
            sw.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

> Progress bar class:

```
Private Sub FileWriting_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 1
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
    For i = ProgressBar1.Minimum To ProgressBar1.Maximum - 2
        Sleep(10)
        ProgressBar1.Value += 2
        ProgressBar1.Value -= 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: your progress bar does really show the progress of anything.  Remove the Sleep statement and there is no reason for it to exist.  It certainly isnt need to report the progress of writing one line of text

Comment: I know it doesn't actually do anything, it is just an aesthetic feature.

Comment: In MSDN for Form.Load _Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time._ A part from this your code has no possibility to show a progress status while the file is written, The two operation are executed in sequence

Comment: why does the do-nothing progress bar have to go on a new form?  put it on the current form and have it do nothing there.

Comment: Don't bother replying, you're not solving it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do such operations without using [Multithreading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck8bc5c6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) so i changed some parts of your code like this:

`Public Class FileWriting`

```
Private Sub FileWriting_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() setprogressbarminmax()))
    Dim min_value As Integer = 0
    Dim max_value As Integer = 0

    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() min_value = ProgressBar1.Minimum))
    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() max_value = ProgressBar1.Maximum))

    For i = min_value To max_value
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
        If i < 99 Then
            Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() setprogvalue()))
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub setprogressbarminmax()
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 1 : ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
End Sub

Private Sub setprogvalue()
    ProgressBar1.Value += 2
    ProgressBar1.Value -= 1
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

`End Class`

Comment: also you can find more info about BackgroundWorker [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)